# Where do I get Golden Razz Berries from?

Tags: pokemon-go

I had no luck finding any reliable source on where one can get *Golden Razz Berries*. I could imagine getting it either from raids or from pokestops (or maybe as a level-up reward).

**Does someone have any reliable source or has maybe even experienced theirself where Golden Razz Berries drop?**

Comment: Those who say you can get them from Pokestops are misinformed. You can only get them from raids (any tier)

Comment: May the downvoter please explain the mistakes I made, just so i could try not to make them anymore in the future?

Comment: Didn't downvote, but rumors generally aren't good backup for a question. If there is contradictory information you should be able to point (link) to it or not mention it at all.

Comment: @Communisty Thanks! I'll edit my question accordingly to not mention dubious sources anymore!

Comment: [Here](http://www.razzies.com/) :-D

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can only get Golden Razz Berries as a drop from defeating a raid boss. The higher tier the raid is, the higher number of drops you can get, including Golden Razz Berries. I've personally received 10+ from defeating tier 3-4 raids.

From [Pokemon GO Hub](https://pokemongohub.net/gym-raid-update/golden-razz-berry/):

> Pokémon GO Golden Razz Berry is a special variant of the commonly known Razz Berry. It can be used for two purposes: fully restoring a Gym Defender’s motivation meter and drastically increasing your chance to capture a wild Pokémon.
>
> Golden Razz Berries drop in Raid Battles, along with Technical Machines and Rare Candy.

Comment: 10+ Golden Razz? Here I am getting 21 Revives >.>

Comment: @Wondercricket well that happens, too. I get a ton of Golden Razz Berries instead of TMs or Rare Candies, so don't be too jealous...

Comment: Ah ok thanks! Furthermore I didn't know TMs have been added to the game!

Comment: @ParkerHalo they probably work differently than you're thinking-- they just reroll a Pokémon's move (there's fast and charge TMs)

Comment: @Vemonus Does the reroll just randomly select a new attack? Or is the chance of getting a good attack increased somehow?

Comment: @ParkerHalo pretty sure it's just a reroll. Plus, it's not like the game can know what you consider good and desirable in a moveset :p

Comment: @Vemonus Yeah thats right. I hope I'll find a ChargedTM, since my Gyarados has a really bad Charged attack :/

Comment: It's a reroll, but you're guaranteed not to get the same move back.  So for most fast moves, it's 100% guaranteed (since there are generally only 2 fast moves), while for charge moves it's 50% most of the time since most have 3 charge moves.

Answer (score 14):

As stated on [Niantic's website](https://support.pokemongo.nianticlabs.com/hc/en-us/articles/115009004687-What-s-changing-in-Pok%C3%A9mon-GO-), Golden Razz Berry can only be acquired by participating in raid battles

> We’re releasing four new items that can **only be unlocked by participating in Raids**: Golden Razz Berry, Fast TM, Charged TM, and Rare Candy.

Answer (score 0):

Golden Razz Berries are rewards from successfully defeating a raid boss.

The silph road did some research into the number of berries (and other rewards) you'll receive.

In terms of golden razz berries you can receive from a level 1 raid - 1 berry per bundle, level 2 - 2 berries, level 3+ - 3 berries.

The number of bundles you receive per raid depends on what level raid you did and is closely linked to the number of premier balls you receive. This ranges from 1 bundle for a level 1 raid where you receive 6 balls, to 10 bundles for a level 5 raid where you receive 13+ balls.

You can find out more about the research in [their research article](https://thesilphroad.com/science/raid-rewards-secret-multipliers)